# Dividing one result of a query by the result of another

Tags: mysql, sql

I can run

```
SELECT killedby, COUNT(killedby) killcount FROM games_playerinfo WHERE killedby != '' GROUP BY killedby
```

ond get

```
killedby    killcount
Player1         1
Player2         1
```

and I can run

```
SELECT ign, COUNT(ign) numberofgames FROM games_playerinfo GROUP by ign
```

and get

```
ign numberofgames
player1 7
player2 3
player3 3
player4 3
```

I want to divide the each result of the first query by the result of the 2nd query for each user in the first query.

So the result should be

```
ign      avgkillcount
player1  0.1429
player2  0.333333
```

I want to do this in one query so I can limit the results.
I've tried using INNER JOINS but I don't think I understand joins well enough to even know if it can achieve what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  t1.ign,
  (t1.numberofgames / t2.killcount) AS avgkillcount
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      ign, 
      COUNT(ign) numberofgames 
    FROM games_playerinfo 
    GROUP by ign
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
      killedby, 
      COUNT(killedby) killcount
    FROM games_playerinfo 
    WHERE killedby != ''
    GROUP BY killedby
) t2 ON t1.ign = t2.killedby;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12e47/1)

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
SELECT g1.killedby ign,
       COUNT(g1.killedby)/(SELECT COUNT(ign) numberofgames 
                                  FROM games_playerinfo 
                                  WHERE ign = g1.killedby
                                  GROUP by ign) avgkillcount
FROM games_playerinfo g1
WHERE g1.killedby != '' 
GROUP BY g1.killedby
```